# Cannot run bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I tried to make a bash script to open a file in VS code but it is giving the error:

```
Bash: ./open.sh: Permission denied
```

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
code  $1
```

Comment: Have you tried to set correct permissions to bash script?

Comment: And by correct permissions you mean setting it as executable: `chmod +x ./open.sh`

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu version mentioned what does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, you can type `chmod +x ./open.sh`.

In Nautilus (or whatever file manager you use), you can find a **Permissions** tab, then the checkbox that says *Allow executing file as program*, and clicking it so it shows the check-mark.

Comment: I did that I can show you the "ls -l" result. Do you what to see it?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manav manav 0 Mar  2 14:04 open.sh

 the output of ls -l

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions in Nautilus through the root account?

Comment: I tryed to change the permissions using the root account is the trerminal

Comment: Have you tried using the root account to make a new document, copying and pasting the code from the original script, saving it as the same name in the same directory, and tried running that?

Comment: no, I will try that.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: That's really strange, never heard of something like that happen before. Are you able to use a virtual machine and try to do the same thing and see if it does anything different?

Comment: I don't know how to set up a VM. And I am also up to date on my computer, just so if  you know of a bug you can tell me.

Comment: You can use a software called Oracle VirtualBox, there are plenty of tutorials on the Magical red website called YouTube. You can search how to set up Ubuntu in virtualbox. You can head over to https://ubuntu.com and download an .iso file to use inside Virtualbox

Comment: I didn't try to use a VM but, I have installed ubuntu 22.04 but it still does not work.